# Quartz thread count

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz and want to change it's thread pool size dynamically, does anybody know how to reset `org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount` programatically ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I create an implementation of the ThreadPool that allow to change dynamically the thread count.

https://github.com/epiresdasilva/quartz-dynamic-pool

Basically what you have to do is:

- Add the following property in the quartz configuration:

  ```
  org.quartz.threadPool.class=br.com.evandropires.quartz.impl.ExecutorServiceThreadPool
  ```
- Get the thread pool instance and resize your thread count:

  ```
  DynamicThreadPool threadPool = DynamicThreadPoolRepository.getInstance().lookup(quartzSchedulerName);
  threadPool.doResize(yourNewPoolSize);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

it's little bit late but somebody might find it usefull. I'm also quite bit of new to the quartz scheduler but here's how i do in 2.2.3.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", size);
/*
   set some other properties...
*/
SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(prop);
Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();
```